# Spring MVC - Handling Errors, Form Submits with Multiple forms

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a .JSP file that has three forms on it whose fields are dynamically shown/hidden based on user interaction with Javascript/Jquery elements.The forms are spring forms sending their action to a URL that matches a controller.

The issue is that when I submit a form, and it does not validate, the URL the form submitted to stays in the URL. Then any action I take that is URL dependent is basically corrupted because the URL has the form action appended to it.

For example, if my .JSP's normal URL is `/admin/`, and my spring form is:

```
<form:form id="form" method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/createUser" modelAttribute="User">
```

If validation fails my URL will now be `/admin/createUser`. If I am then taking some action using Javascript/Jquery the URL is no longer a valid way to navigate. I could just work around the URL but it just seems...un-ideal.

I have tried using redirects like: `"redirect:/admin/"`, but spring validation will not work with this because you are basically just reloading the page.

Are there any best-practice or "elegant" solutions to this, or something really simple that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

The redirection should probably be done on the client side anyways with a param of returnToURL, and as for error handling in Spring, you can register method as error handler to return proper error responses:

```
class YourController {

    /**
    * see @link{org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler}
    */
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public @ResponseBody String handleException(Exception e, HttpServletResponse rsp) {
        // set the response status
        return "{\"error\" : ...}"'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get error you can return error message to  a custom error page to display the error message. or in your case you can return the admin page again..
here is some example code .

---

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "/createUser" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView create(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        
        if(user == null){
            
            Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
            model.put("errorCode", "00");
            model.put("errorText", "Error Message Here");
            return new ModelAndView("error_page", model);
        }
        
        return new ModelAndView("Welcome_page");
    }
```